GraphQL returns null data, even tho data is correctly returned
everyone.
I am trying to learn GraphQL. I am using NestJs with CSQR modules and GraphQl.
So I have a Query that returns a list of users including data for pagination, however the data is correctly returned when I logit into the console, but its not returned in the GraphQL playground.
This is my Resolver:
@Resolver()
export default class UserResolver {
    constructor(
        private readonly commandBus: CommandBus,
        private readonly queryBus: QueryBus,
    ) {}

    @Query(() => String)
    hello(): string {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    @Query(() => PaginatedUsersResponse)
    async getUsers(
        @Args("page", { type: () => Int, defaultValue: 1 }) page: number,
        @Args("limit", { type: () => Int, defaultValue: 10 }) limit: number,
    ) {
        const t = await this.queryBus.execute(new GetUsersQuery(page, limit));
        console.log(t);
        return t;
    }

    @Mutation(() => GenericResponse)
    async CreateUser(@Args("createUser") dto: CreateUserDto): Promise<GenericResponse> {
        const { email, firstName, lastName, password } = dto;
        const response = await this.commandBus.execute(
            new CreateUserCommand(firstName, lastName, password, email),
        );
        return response;
    }
}


This is my Query:
export class GetUsersQuery {
    constructor(
        public page: number,
        public limit: number,
    ) {}
}

@QueryHandler(GetUsersQuery)
export default class GetUsersQueryHandler implements IQueryHandler<GetUsersQuery> {
    constructor(
        @InjectEntityManager() private readonly entityManager: EntityManager,
        @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: Mapper,
    ) {}

    async execute(query: GetUsersQuery): Promise<PaginatedUsersResponse> {
        const { page, limit } = query;
        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

        const [users, total] = await this.entityManager.findAndCount(User, {
            skip,
            take: limit,
        });

        const userDtos = this.mapper.mapArray(users, User, UserListItemDto);

        return new PaginatedUsersResponse(userDtos, total, page, limit);
    }
}


This is my PageinatedUserResponse and PaginatedList and UserListItemDto:
@ObjectType()
export default class PaginatedUsersResponse extends PaginatedList {
    @Field(() => [UserListItemDto], { nullable: true })
    items?: UserListItemDto[];

    constructor(items?: UserListItemDto[], total?: number, page?: number, limit?: number) {
        super(total, page, limit);
        this.items = items;
    }
}



@ObjectType()
export default class UserListItemDto {
    @Field(() => String)
    Id: string;

    @Field(() => String)
    Email: string;

    @Field(() => String)
    FirstName: string;

    @Field(() => String)
    LastName: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export default class PaginatedList {
    @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
    total?: number;

    @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
    page?: number;

    @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
    limit?: number;

    constructor(total?: number, page?: number, limit?: number) {
        this.total = total;
        this.page = page;
        this.limit = limit;
    }
}

This is the data returned by the console.log:
PaginatedUsersResponse {
  total: 18,
  page: 1,
  limit: 5,
  items: [
    UserListItemDto {
      Id: '3666210e-be8e-4b67-808b-bae505c6245e',
      Email: 'admin@test.com',
      FirstName: 'admin',
      LastName: 'Admin'
    },
    UserListItemDto {
      Id: '6284edb9-0ad9-4c59-81b3-cf28e1fca1a0',
      Email: 'admin@test2.com',
      FirstName: 'admin',
      LastName: 'Admin'
    },
    UserListItemDto {
      Id: '67fd1df6-c231-42a4-bbaa-5380a3edba08',
      Email: 'admin@test3.com',
      FirstName: 'admin',
      LastName: 'Admin'
    },
    UserListItemDto {
      Id: '6fbd3b0c-1c30-4685-aa4d-eff5bff3923b',
      Email: 'admin@test4.com',
      FirstName: 'admin',
      LastName: 'Admin'
    },
    UserListItemDto {
      Id: '54fc4abe-2fe8-4763-9a14-a38c4abeb449',
      Email: 'john.doe@example.com',
      FirstName: 'John',
      LastName: 'Doe'
    }
  ]
}


And this is my Query in the GraphQL playground:
query GetUsers($page: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
  getUsers(page: $page, limit: $limit) {
    items {
      Id
      Email
      FirstName
      LastName
    }
    total
    page
    limit
  }
}


Pagination variables:
{
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 5
}


And this is what is returned:
{
  "data": {
    "getUsers": {
      "items": null,
      "total": null,
      "page": null,
      "limit": null
    }
  }
}

I tried to create seperate type but it didnt work, the data was still returned as null

did you try to add .lean()?
